# Отбор значений за определенный период времени

Tags: sql, sql-server

Для отчета исходя из столбца `[Дата заказа]` на определенную дату @bdate требуется найти количество заказов за  текущий месяц, за неделю и за прошедшие сутки.

```
DECLARE @bdate DATETIME =  Cast('08.02.2017 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)

    SELECT
     @bdate as data
    ,[Заказ ]
    ,[Дата заказа]
     FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @bdate DATETIME =  Cast('08.02.2017 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)

select sum(case when [Дата заказа] >= @bdate and [Дата заказа] < DATEADD(d,1,@bdate) then 1 end) day,
       sum(case when DATEPART(iso_week,[Дата заказа])=DATEPART(iso_week,@bdate) then 1 end) week,
       sum(case when DATEPART(m,[Дата заказа])=DATEPART(m,@bdate) then 1 end) month
  from datetest
 where [Дата заказа] between DATEADD(d, -7, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @bdate), 0))
                         and DATEADD(d, 7, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @bdate) + 1, 0))
```

В условии where отбираем записи за месяц, с запасом в +-7 дней, на случай, если текущая неделя окажется за границами текущего месяца. Условие в первом sum() рассчитано на подсчет заказов в тех сутках, которые заданы параметром. Если "прошедшие" это на день раньше - скорректируйте условие. Неделя берется календарная, с понедельника по воскресенье, включающая указанный день.